# ExtJs getRecord() function of form does not work

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs5

I would like to get my values from my form through the getRecord() function.
This is the result im currently getting from form.getRecord():

[image: getRecord]

The data object is empty.

This is my controller:

```
onAddNewsClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {

    var win = this.getNewsEdit();
    if(!win){
        win = Ext.create('widget.newsedit');
    }
    this.getNewsPanel().loadRecord(Ext.create('model.news'));
    console.log(this.getNewsPanel());
    this.adding = true;
    win.show();
},

OnSaveNewsClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {

    var form = this.getNewsPanel();
    console.log(form);
    var selectedRecord = form.getRecord();
    console.log(selectedRecord);
    if (this.adding) {
        this.adding = undefined;
    }
}
```

The correspoding Model:

```
Ext.define('mobile_admin.model.News', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
alias: 'model.news',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Field'
],

fields: [
    {
        name: 'title'
    },
    {
        name: 'newscontent'
    },
    {
        name: 'newsdate'
    },
    {
        name: 'status'
    }
]});
```

With form.getValues() I get all the values of the form.
[image: getValues]

It feels like that the model is not connecting to the form. In the form I put the necessary name connection: (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-loadRecord)

My Form items:

```
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Titel',
        name: 'title'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Datum',
        name: 'newsdate'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'htmleditor',
        height: 150,
        width: 600,
        fieldLabel: 'Inhalt',
        name: 'newscontent',
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Status',
        name: 'status'
    },
]
```

Anyone has an idea?
I use ExtJs (5.1.3).

//EDIT:
I found out that I can set the record like this:

```
var b = form.getRecord()
b.set(form.getValues()
```

Shouln't this ExtJs do automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What loadRecord really do is just setting values. Form don't use this record any more. Here is form docs:

```
loadRecord: function(record) {
    this._record = record;
    return this.setValues(record.getData());
},
```

You asked if setting values to record can be done automatically. Yes, it is possible, but binding is required.

I prepared a sample code:

```
Ext.define('mobile_admin.model.News', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.news',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.field.Field'
    ],

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'title', defaultValue : 'test'
        },
        {
            name: 'newscontent'
        },
        {
            name: 'newsdate'
        },
        {
            name: 'status'
        }
    ]
});

Ext.define('mobile_admin.form.ViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.formpanel',

    links : {
        theModel : {
            type : 'mobile_admin.model.News',
            create : true
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('mobile_admin.form.formpanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.newsedit',
    viewModel : 'formpanel',

    items : [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Titel',
            name: 'title',
            bind : {
                value : '{theModel.title}'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Datum',
            name: 'newsdate',
            bind : {
                value : '{theModel.newsdate}'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'htmleditor',
            height: 150,
            width: 600,
            fieldLabel: 'Inhalt',
            name: 'newscontent',
            bind : {
                value : '{theModel.newscontent}'
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Status',
            name: 'status',
            bind : {
                value : '{theModel.status}'
            }
        }],

    buttons : [{
        text : 'Save',
        handler : function(button) {
            var vM = button.up('form').getViewModel();
            vM.notify();
            console.log(vM.get('theModel').getData());
        }
    }]
});

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        debugger;
        var form = Ext.widget('newsedit');
        var window = Ext.widget('window', {
            items : form
        });
        window.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Although your answer might be correct using only links in your answers isn't good at all. If the links ever go offline your answer becomes invalid. Links are meant to improve your answer not replace it. I would highly suggest editing your answer to actually answer the question in the answer body it self.